# Given $P(A), P(B), P(C)$ and that $A, B, C$ are independent, what is the probability that exactly two of the three events occur?

Tags: probability, independence

Note that $(X \cap Y^c \cap Z) \cap (X \cap Y \cap Z^c) = \emptyset$, since $Z \cap Z^c = \emptyset$. Thus, the events $A \cap B \cap C^c$, $A \cap B^c \cap C$ and $A^c \cap B \cap C$ are mutually disjoint. So, we are interested in finding:

$$ P(E) = P(A \cap B \cap C^c) + P(A \cap B^c \cap C) + P(A^c \cap B \cap C)$$

The problem tells us that the three events $A, B, C$ are independent; note that this is different from $A, B, C$ being mutually independent, as we only have:

$$ P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C) $$

The solution to the problem hinges upon the following sub-problem: can we determine $P(A \cap B \cap C^c)$ using the information given?

If yes, then by symmetry, we should be able to determine the probability of $P(A \cap B^c \cap C)$ and $P(A^c \cap B \cap C)$.

I am not able to figure out $P(A \cap B^c \cap C)$ using the given information. Does we not have enough information?

Comment: I've seen the distinction between "pairwise independent" and "independent" but usually "independent" and "mutually independent" are synonyms (the latter possibly was made simply to clarify it's not "pairwise").  What is your distinction between "independent" and "mutually independent"?

Comment: If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are independent, then we also have $\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)$ and so on.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I felt there was a distinction because of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Mutual_independence

Comment: That just says it's possible to have $P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$ without them being pairwise independent.  Basically, $P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$ is insufficient to show that the events are independent.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I am an idiot. Thank you.